# Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to render a child, if it has to be rendered due to a condition.
The problem is the Father component accepts ReactElement or ReactElement[] and I can't understand how to include also a null child.

[Here the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-15clxj?file=/src/App.tsx)

I'm also aware of ReactNode type, but then I have to change tons of code, so I would prefer keep using ReactElement.

Edit, a better explanation of my problem:

In the linked code, in App.tsx:12 typescript complains about the possibile null for the children.

Comment: Its not very clear what exactly you are asking. I've looked at your sandbox and I can't see any errors... What do you mean by 'trying to render a child'? You can do that in react by simply doing `{props.children}`

Comment: sorry, I edit my answer for a better clarification. basically everything works fine in my code. The only problem is in the App.tsx line 12 for a Typescript's issue